# Wrap widgets according to minimum size and then stretch them to fill available width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

`Wrap` cannot contain `Expanded` widgets, so is there another way to have its children laid out according to their minimum required width, but then make them fill the space using `spaceBetween` to stretch only with respect to the specified `spacing`?

```
|---item---| |--item--|
|--------item---------|
```

rather than

```
|-item-|       |-item-|
|-item-|
```

Comment: But you still want items to shift to the next line if they are too big?

Comment: exactly. the stretching is supposed to occur _after_ wrapping has occurred using the minimum widths of the elements.

Comment: What you are asking for Flutter to do is very counter intuitive because you are asking for the Children of a Parent Widget to readjust their size after the Parent has calculated how it will fit the Children, but that means that then the Parent would have to recalculate how the Children fit based on their new sizes. It would likely become an infinite loop.

Comment: That being said, there is a chance that the `IntrinsicWidth` widget might be useful to solve this.

Comment: `LayoutBuilder` has a problem with that approach...
I don't get why this would be counterintuitive though? As I understand it, layouting occurs in two phases: traverse the widget tree passing on constraints (which should use the minimum required width for items here to allocate the rows), then go back up the tree and do the actual layout - the WrapAlignment has to be applied anyway at some point, so why wouldn't there be an option like `MainAxisAlignment.stretch` here?

Comment: The Wrap decides where to put it's children depending on their size. Then the Children would have to resize and fully fit the Viewport based on which row the parent decided to put them, and then resize again. I haven't seen a combination of Widgets that allows this to happen. If you do find it, please share.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still facing issue to achieving the above result check this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flex_list). Also keep an eye on this [flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135301).

Answer (score -2):

There's a package called [separated_row](https://pub.dev/packages/separated_row). It's made for that.

All you have to do is to:

- Provider a separator widget in its `separatorBuilder` parameter (e.g padding).
- Wrap each child item in an `Expanded` widget.

  ```
  SeparatedRow(
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Text("Item 1"),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text("Item 2"),
      ),
    ],
  )
  ```

You can also set its `includeOuterSeparators` parameter to `true` to add the separator at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: That doesn't seem to provide the functionality for wrapping, though